# Finding interest rate automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel

would really appreciate the help rendered. I'm told to come up with an excel document that disable the usage of any add ons and macro. I need to find interest rate where my inputs correspond to a total fund value (e.g. 120=100(1+i)^2+100(1+i)^1.5) .The interest rate also need to automatically update itself when there are changes in input(i.e cash flow and years). I have tried goal seek, but the main issue here is that goal seek doesnt update on its own if i were to change any of the inputs.

Thanks for any feedback given.

Comment: it is not really clear what you need. Please explain how your worksheet looks. That input data you have and what output data you want (exactly)?

Comment: We aren't a script writing service, so you will have to do the work. There are tons of excel examples, ([like this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rate-function-HP010342819.aspx) and [this](http://best-excel-tutorial.com/59-tips-and-tricks/157-real-interest-rate)), on the Internet on how to calculate interest. Find something that is close to what you need and work with it. When you get stuck, [edit] your question with what you've tried and where you're stuck and we can help from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to get at, and I think that you can accomplish it using `XIRR`.

It sounds like you want to calculate the discount rate required for a cash flow to meet some particular present value. This sounds a lot like the definition of IRR, which is the discount rate required for a cash flow to have a present value of zero. If we make one small adjustment, we can use that to target some value other than zero.

If you look in my image below, you'll see that I have two columns of values: "Cash Flow" and "IRR Target Row". They are identical to each other, except the "IRR Target Row" (which is actually a column... oops!) has subtracted out our "Target value" (in cell I4) from the t=0 period.

Using `=XIRR(F3:F14,D3:D14)` in cell I5, we can see what discount rate is required to have our adjusted cash flow have a present value of zero. Then, since the adjustment that we made in t=0 won't be discounted in a PV (since it's at t=0), that IRR gives us the discount rate to use to have `=XNPV(I6,E3:E14,D3:D14)` (in cell E1) be equal to our target value.

[image: Using XIRR to target a certain NPV]